# Why are the last five parshiyos of sefer Shemos not in sefer Vayikra?

Tags: mishkan-tabernacle, shemot-exodus, parashat-teruma, sefer-vayikra

Since parshiyos Terumah through Pekudei deal with the building and vessels of the Mishkan and the priestly garments, why are they in Sefer Shemos and not in Sefer Vayikra? Isn't Shemos supposed to be about the redemption from Egypt?

Answer (score 10):

The Netziv in his introduction to Sh'mos says that the ultimate purpose is NOT the redemption from Egypt, but the building of the mishkan and subsequent dwelling of the Shekhina.
Remember, the exodus itself happens relatively soon in the sefer, while matan torah and the mishkan take up a much larger portion.

Answer (score 9):

The book of Exodus ends with "as God's presence was with them, for all their travels."  The Ramban explains that they didn't achieve full redemption from Egypt until that point.  Now they had a post-Egyptian purpose and identity.